# Cancel Unloaded event in a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I implemented a WPF application which use NavigationService to navigate between pages.
When I switch from a page to another one, the Unloaded event is raised for each graphical element that belongs to the former page.
Is there a way to cancel that event without having access to the graphical elements but only to the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Unloaded (and Loaded, for that matter) are not Tunneling events, I don't think there's any way to cancel this at the high level.

I'm curious as to what you are trying to achieve.  Are you freeing resources associated with the child items?  Are you concerned about the impact of returning to this page and re-initializing the resources?  If so, perhaps an application cache is a better place to store them, so that you can tell when they were initialized, how often they were used, etc.  This would also give you a centralized place to clean up cached resources in the case of memory pressure or a situation where you knew that resources from previous steps are invalid (e.g. you have finished a wizard, so you know you don't need any of the resources associated with earlier steps in the wizard).

Alternately, if you're looking for an opportunity to cancel the navigation entirely, I believe you're looking for the **Navigating** event.  Canceling this event should halt the loading of the new resource and prevent the current page from changing.

--Adding information about a caching solution (wouldn't fit in a comment)

My first thought is that you should only optimize once you know something is actually a performance issue in the real world.  If this does turn out to be a problem, you could create a singleton caching object that lives in your application to manage these objects.  I'm sure there are some pre-built solutions that I am unaware of, but a Dictionary wrapped in an interface with string keys wrapped in a Singeton object would be sufficient for a simple application.  You could then access it through a simple interface

```
CustomApplicationObjectCache[CACHE_KEY_CONSTANT_STRING] = new VisualBrush(...); //Or whatever type you have
```

Unless you are dealing with some very heavy-weight objects or object graphs, though, I suspect caching would be overkill and would probably get in the way of .NET doing the correct thing for garbage collection.  I would recommend profiling your application and seeing if this is actually a performance problem for you.

Comment: You guess, I'm concerned about the impact of returning to this page and re-initializing the resources. Could you explain me what you mean for an application cache?

Answer (score 3):

`Unloaded` is fired when the PresentationSource is disconnected, which is after the navigation to another page has already taken place.

WPF takes great care to ensure that `Unloaded` is fired on every control that has its `PresentationSource` disconnected, so the only way to prevent `Unloaded` from firing on your graphical elements is prevent the `PresentationSource` from being disconnected.  There are several ways to accomplish this:

**Solution 1: Cancel the Navigating event**

One way to accomplish this is to cancel the `Navigating` event, forcing the user to stay on the same page.  This will of course prevent the `PresentationSource` from being disconnected so the `Unloaded` event won't fire.  This may or may not be a viable solution, depending on your particular UI requirements.

**Solution 2: Parent your elements outside the navigation frame**

Using an `AdornerLayer` it is possible to have controls outside the navigation frame appear as if they were actually within the navigation frame.  Since the visual tree outside the navigation frame doesn't change while navigating, the `PresentationSource` is never disconnected from the `Adorner`.

**Solution 3: Use your own PresentationSource**

If you must absolutely prevent your graphical elements from ever being disconnected, you can implement your own `PresentationSource`.  Put your graphical elements under your custom `PresentationSource`, then draw them onto the real `PresentationSource` using a `DrawingContext`.  You may also need to redirect input events if you want your controls to interact.  Note that this solution is quite complex and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Could you explain your 2nd solution a little bit more and provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question here. I know exactly what you want to achieve. This always works for me:

```
private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ConditionsMet) { e.Handled = true; }

            //if ConditionsMet the Unloaded event will be set to true henceforth keeping your control in the VisualTree - your control does not Unload
```